# Method not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Tags: iphone, llvm, clang

Does anyone know what this LLVM warning means:

```
Method '-retry' not found (return type defaults to 'id') in sourceFile.m
```

I get this warning on the following line of sourceFile.m:

```
[self.operation retry];
```

My class has a variable 'operation', which is a custom class extending NSOperation.

```
MyCustomOperation* operation;

@property (nonatomic, retain) MyCustomOperation* operation;
```

My custom operation class has a method:

```
- (void) retry;
```

Everything seems to work, but I'd sure love to get rid of my warnings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the method declaration `- (void) retry;` in the interface too, not just the implementation?

Comment: yes, the method is defined in the header file of the custom operation.

Comment: double check the retry method to make sure it's not returning anything, since it's void.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if you've imported `MyCustomOperation.h`.